# Boot Error: EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting

Tags: boot, system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on a custom built PC. ( [Asus X-99 WS  Motherboard](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/X99E_WS/specifications/)) with DDR4 RAM and I'm having issues installing it properly. When I boot into the startup USB drive I get a screen flash with the error

```
20.469251 EDAC sbridge: ECC is disabled. Aborting
[20.469251] EDAC sbridge: couldn't find mci handler
```

The installation process continues normally after this but once the OS is installed and I boot into it the OS has low performance. The display takes several seconds to respond (over 5-10 seconds to respond to any click!) and screens appear to 'wipe' the screen during transitions.

I have had previous versions of Ubuntu on manufactured PC's and haven't had any issues during or after installation, so I feel this might be related to my build.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: after a lot of fiddling it turns out it had nothing to do with the motherboard. the issue was my graphics card. there are other posts about this and ill link them if i can find them again.